# FloodFill in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, bitmapdata

I have been making a basic painting application similar to MS-Paint with basic paint, eraser and fill tools. It's this last one that's giving me some trouble.

I'm pretty new to using BitmapData but the idea is that when the user clicks the board, it triggers the startFloodFill method. This is shown below:

```
public static function startFloodFill(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("FLOODFILL");
        var boardRef:MovieClip = e.currentTarget.parent.board;                      //Creates a reference to the board
        var boardData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(boardRef.width, boardRef.height); //Creates a new BitmapData with the same size as boardRef
        boardData.floodFill(e.localX, e.localY, 0x00CCCCCC);                        //Applies the FloodFill
        boardData.draw(boardRef);                                                   //Saves the boardRef as bitmapData
        boardRef.bitmapData = boardData;                                            //Updates the board
            boardRef.parent.addChild(boardRef);
    }
```

Can anybody tell me what I've done wrong here? When I click, the board does not change. I expected the FloodFill to fill the entire bitmap with the chosen colour as the board is blank when I click.

I also tried replacing the last two lines with:

```
boardRef.addChild(new Bitmap(boardData) );                              //Updates the board
```

Thanks

Comment: What type of an object is `boardRef`? A `Bitmap`? Why does it have a `bitmapData` property? If it doesn't, why do you assign that? If it's really a `Bitmap`, you should instead do a `floodFill` vs its `bitmapData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you first use the `floodFill`, and then use the `draw` method, which actually fills the `BitmapData` with whatever param you give it - in your case it's the `boardRef`.

You should first draw the `boardRef` into the `boardData`, and then use `floodFill`. At the end, you need to create new `Bitmap` and display it.

Now you are setting the `bitmapData` of a `MovieClip`?! Don't know what you wanted, but you just need to add new child (new Bitmap)